# generate a .tab file with filenames and paths separated by tab

Tags: linux, genome

I have just started learning linux CLI. I am using snippy tool for comparing multiple files that require a .tab format file. This tab formatted file should be consisting of the paths and filenames separated by tab (\t).

I have run this two commands separately to generate a list of filenames and paths.

```
find $(pwd)/*.fna > /home/fan/onas/filenames.tab
```

and

```
ls > filenames.tab
```

but whenever I run this command to check the tabs in file. There is no tab (\t) exists inside the file.

```
cat -vet filenames.tab
```

I have used also this command to replace the \n with \t. But it doesn't work here.

```
sed 's/\n/\t/g' filenames.tab > file2.tab
```

In short, I'm trying to generate a file having filenames and paths separated by tabs or .tab format. Could somebody help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `printf`...

```
printf "%s\t" $(ls -A $(pwd)) >files.tab
```

...formating output of `ls -A` (also hidden files) separated with tabs to (`>`) files.tab.

> If your `printf` also supports `-v` then you can do...

```
printf -v FILES "%s\t" $(ls -A $(pwd))
echo ${FILES}
```

> But the tabs sadly get lost. Writing it to a file like in the first example corrects it...

```
printf "%s\t" ${FILES} >files.tab
```

Wonder why only one `%s\t`? Hm, its like a `foreach` on an array. For each element in the whitespace separated list `printf` do the `%s\t` and throws other whitespace away.